# How do i let the user know the server is updating on the back end and their change is not active yet?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, usability-testing, user-centered-design, ux-designer

Imagine a long list of websites that you can either allow or block from your internet. The user can go down the list and block every single one relatively quickly, however on the backend each of these websites can take anywhere from 5 seconds to 1 minute. This can build up quickly if, say, 30 websites blocked at the max time of 1 min each, it could take 30 mins. The user is not stuck on the page and they are free to do whatever they please on the app. Is there any clear way to indicate to the user that their change is not immediately ready? I thought about adding a small tooltip/popup saying "changes are being added...", but is there a drawback because the user is not forced to go on the screen, they won't see when it is completed?

Comment: Are you looking for a method not limited to the page they made the changes on? Like email? Text? Possibly a browser extension? Mobile notification? Or something on the block edit page that makes it clear changes take time. Can you estimate the amount of time each change will take?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, block/unblock are the only actions there for list items:

I think you need to add disable class (may be only the gray font color) on that item on the list which has been acted upon by user. Then you can add a tooltip for them.

Once, user is used to reading a tooltip, it will be actually easy for him/her to recognize the acted links and wait.

Keep a short and simple tooltip: Blocking... or Unblocking...

And after action is finished, change the state of the item.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the changes you can have a pop up saying something along the lines of "The changes may take a few minutes to take affect, feel free to browse while you wait"

You can also add a loading circle next to each item so they can check back on the page and see the progress.

Answer (score 0):

You could inform user on his e-mail address. And declare this in system message: Block request is being placed, once done you will receive an E-mail confirmation.